# Solve $(2^x+3^x+5^x)^3=160^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponential-function, exponentiation, radicals

The question is to find all real solutions of the equation:

$$(2^x+3^x+5^x)^3=160^x$$

Using Wolfram, I can check that $x=3$ is the only solution, but I'm having trouble trying to find it by hand.

First idea was try to use AM-GM inequality. Some algebric manipulation also didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Isn't it enough to divide both sides by $160^x$ and exploit convexity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's $f(x)=0$, where
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{160}}\right)^x+\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{160}}\right)^x+\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt[3]{160}}\right)^x-1.$$
But $f$ is a decreasing function and the rest for you.

Comment: Is there any way to find the answer without testing?

Comment: @Arnaldo Since $f$ is a decreasing function, our equation has one root maximum. But $3$ is a root, which gives the answer: $\{3\}$.  It's not testing, it's just solution of your problem.

Comment: What I meant is once you know that you have just one solution, you then started to test which value of $x$ could give you the solution. Did you do that process?

Comment: @Arnaldo The graph of a decreasing function can cross the $x$- axis in one point maximum. Draw it! We see that $(3,0)$ is a common, Thus, it's an unique point.

Comment: Thanks Michael, we are talking the same thing but just using different words.

Answer (score 5):

The equation can be written as

$$ \left(\frac{2}{160^{1/3}}\right)^x +  \left(\frac{3}{160^{1/3}}\right)^x
+ \left(\frac{5}{160^{1/3}}\right)^x = 1$$

The left side is a decreasing function of $x$, since $$\frac{2}{160^{1/3}} < \frac{3}{160^{1/3}} < \frac{5}{160^{1/3}} < 1 $$

Comment: Is there any way to find the answer without testing?

Comment: @Arnaldo: This answer proves there can only be one solution. So once we have found one, then we are sure to be done.

Comment: @mathreadler: You are right. My question was how to find such solution. After talk a little with Michael, I'm convinced that if we don't use a numerical method we must have luck to have a easy solution and find it by testing some values of $x$ or use some graph interpretation.

Comment: If you want a closed-form solution, there will be very little hope unless $x$ is an integer.  Since $160^x$ must be the cube of an integer, that integer must be divisible by $3$.  So the first thing to try is $x=3$.

Comment: Thank you Robert. You got my point.